# Double tabs in PyCharm 2022.2.1 in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

Please advise how to config the tabs behavior inside PyCharm 2022.2.1 and Jupyter Notebook.

I have checked inside the tabs and spaces and all configs are fine but inside the notebook I see it is doubling the tabs (8 instead 4 spaces).

How can I change it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured out the issue. When I open the file and change .ipynb to .py or playing with the formats it messes with the tabs size.
Just opened a new notebook in my PyCharm and copied my code. Voila, worked :)
Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the indent to 4 spaces by configuring the tab and indent settings for the current *.ipynb file under the status bar at the bottom of the main window.

[image: screenshot of editor footer bar with indentation configuration]